# CSV-like data in script to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I've got a list of cities with associated lon,lat values that I'd like to turn into a DataFrame, but instead of reading from a CSV file, I want to have the user modify or add to these city,lat,lon values into a cell in an IPython notebook.  Right now I have this solution that works, but it seems a bit ugly:

```
import pandas as pd
sta =  array([
        ('Boston',          42.368186, -71.047984),
        ('Provincetown',    42.042745, -70.171180),
        ('Sandwich',        41.767990, -70.466219),
        ('Gloucester',      42.610253, -70.660570)
        ],
        dtype=[('City','|S20'), ('Lat','<f4'), ('Lon', '<f4')])

# Create a Pandas DataFrame
obs = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sta,index='City')
print(obs)
                    Lat        Lon
City                              
Boston        42.368187 -71.047981
Provincetown  42.042744 -70.171181
Sandwich      41.767990 -70.466217
Gloucester    42.610252 -70.660568
```

**Is there a clearer, safer way to create the DataFrame?**

I'm thinking that folks will forget the parenthesis, add a closing ',' on the last line, etc.

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: "add a closing ',' on the last line": if you mean the `Gloucester` line, then that's okay.  In fact, sometimes it's even recommended!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just create a big multiline string that they edit, then use `read_csv` to read it from a StringIO object:

```
x = """
City, Lat, Long
Boston, 42.4, -71.05
Provincetown, 42.04, -70.12
"""

>>> pandas.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(x.strip()), sep=",\s*")
           City    Lat   Long
0        Boston  42.40 -71.05
1  Provincetown  42.04 -70.12
```

Of course, people can still make errors with this (e.g., inserting commas), but the format is simpler.